# Unflushed Requests using Jasmine and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm having problems passing some tests since I've tried using $httpBackend.verifyNoOustandingRequest().

If I don't include this in my afterEach function then the tests pass, however when I do it causes all my tests to fail apart from last one 'should load items from the server'. Each failed tests response is 'Error: unflushed request: 1' apart from the last test.

What I don't understand is that I thought that you only need to worry about flush is when mocking an ajax request and yet its failing all but my actual server test.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
describe('controller: ListCtrl', function(){
beforeEach(module('notesApp'));
var ctrl, loc, mockService, itemServiceS, mockBackend;
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $location, ItemService, $httpBackend){
    spyOn(ItemService, 'list').and.returnValue([{id: 1, label: 'First', done: true}]);
    itemService = ItemService;
    mockBackend = $httpBackend;
    mockBackend.expectGET('/api/note').respond([{id: 1, label: 'Mock'}]);
    ctrl = $controller('ListCtrl');         
    loc = $location;
}));
it('Should have items available on load', function(){
    expect(ctrl.items).toEqual([
        {id: 1, label: 'First', done: true},
        {id: 2, label: 'Second', done: false}
    ]);
});
it('Should have highlight items based on state', function(){
    var item = {id: 1, label: 'First', done: true};
    var actualClass = ctrl.getDoneClass(item);
    expect(actualClass.finished).toBeTruthy();
    expect(actualClass.unfinished).toBeFalsy();

    item.done = false;
    actualClass = ctrl.getDoneClass(item);
    expect(actualClass.finished).toBeFalsy();
    expect(actualClass.unfinished).toBeTruthy()
});
it('should change the url', function(){
    expect(loc.path()).toEqual('');
    ctrl.navigate1();
    expect(loc.path()).toEqual('/some/where/else');
});

it('Should change the url to /some/where', function(){
    expect(loc.path()).toEqual('');
    ctrl.navigate2();
    expect(loc.path()).toEqual('/some/where');
});
it('Should have called through ItemService factory', function(){
    expect(itemService.list).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(itemService.list.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
    expect(ctrl.itemsGet).toEqual([{id: 1, label: 'First', done: true}]);

});
it('Should load items from server', function(){
    expect(ctrl.retrievedItems).toEqual([]);
    mockBackend.flush();
    expect(ctrl.retrievedItems.data).toEqual([{id: 1, label: 'Mock'}]);
});
afterEach(function(){
    mockBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    mockBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
})
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not seeing your controller code I can't know for sure, but it does seem that the mock API request is made as a part of controller initialization.  Therefore the request is always made, and it must always be flushed to satisfy the asserts in your afterEach.

$httpBackend's `expect()` syntax is very strict, you may prefer to use the `when()` syntax, that is looser and more "black box".  You can read about some of the differences in the angularJS [documentation for $httpBackend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.